# Scripts Running Slowly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My scripts each take over a minute to run. They accept triggers from spreadsheet, so the longer they take to run, the more executions build up, and I've started getting failures due to "simultaneous invocations."

I'm running two AutoFill functions (see sample) OnChange, and one script that populates drop-down data validations OnEdit.

```
function accountCreationAutoFill(e){
   Logger.log(e.changeType);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Account Creation Sheet")
  if(e.changeType=='INSERT_ROW'){
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  var needsSourceRange = sheet.getRange("AccountCreationNeedsFormula")
  var needsDestination = sheet.getRange("AccountCreationNeedsAutoFill")
  var contactSourceRange = sheet.getRange("AccountCreationContactFormula")
  var contactDestination = sheet.getRange("AccountCreationContactAutoFill")
  needsSourceRange.autoFill(needsDestination, SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES)
  contactSourceRange.autoFill(contactDestination,SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES)
  sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);}
}
```

I haven't tried anything. I'm new to coding, and it took everything I have just to write the scripts and get them to work in the first place. I don't know how to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: I believe you have forgotten to provide the example. Please do so, as this will be really helpful to understand your problem. But a view general pointers to think of when it comes to execution time. Try do narrow down the range of columns you need to read and write down as far as possible and only read or write once. If you have say 20 columns and 1000 rows these are `20 * 1000 = 20,000` cells to read/ write. So can you provide how big the ranges are that you are selecting in your script and why you are selecting them? Also how many columns and rows are we talking here?

Comment: I think the only way to reduce the time is to reduce the size of your ranges

Comment: worth the read: Best Practices - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices and how to make script run faster - https://quick-adviser.com/how-can-i-make-my-google-script-run-faster/ . Otherwise you really have large range on your sheets.

Answer (score -1):

Combining all functions I wanted to run On Change into one script, so I'm only running one OnChange trigger, shortened average run time by 75%.